# Unable to connect the Botium client with Google DialogFlow

Tags: npm-install, dialogflow-es

Installed npm via mac terminal.

Installed botium client with npm command : `npm install -g botium-cli`

As directed in this [tutorial](https://chatbotsmagazine.com/3-steps-setup-automated-testing-for-google-assistant-and-dialogflow-de42937e57c6) :

Also have got allocated one DialogFlow instance and other details with project configuration as directed in the above linked tutorial.

Error I am getting while establishing the connection between botium client and DialogFlow :

> Auth error:Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start
>   line (node:25129) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot send
>   message to dialogflow container: { Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Getting
>   metadata from plugin failed with error: error:0906D06C:PEM
>   routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
>       at Object.exports.createStatusError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/botium-cli/node_modules/grpc/src/common.js:87:15)
>       at Object.onReceiveStatus (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/botium-cli/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1188:28)
>       at InterceptingListener._callNext (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/botium-cli/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:564:42)
>       at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/botium-cli/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:614:8)
>       at callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/botium-cli/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:841:24)
>   code: 14,   metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} },   details:
>   'Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: error:0906D06C:PEM
>   routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line' }
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/botium-cli/node_modules/botium-connector-dialogflow/dist/botium-connector-dialogflow-cjs.js:222:14
>   (node:25129) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 12) (node:25129) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

If you need, there is also link to [botium client](http://botium-artifacts.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/)

Can anyone help me here with the connection establishment and get going !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same error was coming in my case when I was trying to connect botium to dialogue flow.

In my case `DIALOGFLOW_PRIVATE_KEY` was incorrect. Please check it, if it is starting with

```
------BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
```

and ends with

```
\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n
```

This solved my issue:)

Comment: I had to keep the private key as it is